# MacBook Pro wont boot at all (El capitan)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

My MacBook Pro stopped working. I was using it without a problem, then all of a sudden the screen went Blue.

It didn't respond at all so I did the obvious, force shutdown. Since that moment the computer starts but won't boot the OS.

OSX: El-Capitan
HDD: Momentus XT by Seagate (Hybrid)
FileVault: On
OS starts and gets stuck in the middle (progress bar)

What I've already tried:
Tried boot it with Cmd + D,
Cmd + C,
Shift Key (safe mode),
Disk utility won't even start,
Reset nvram (didn't work),
Swapped my HDD to another MacBook Pro (works flawlessly),
And finally tried booting from an USB stick with El Capitan OS X.

I've read around that it could be Hardware related problem, I'm looking around with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone out there having this specific problem. I found that the Apple's Hardware Test didn't show anything wrong. So I stumbled upon a problem with MacBook's Pro from 2015 (15" and 17" only).

I called Apple Care and they confirmed this. Finally The iShop (Mexico) Support Service changed the Logic Board for free (the faulty video card is embedded to the logic board).

This is the link with the "Apple Replacement Program" if you need to test if your Mac is having the same issue.

[MacBook Pro Video issues](https://www.apple.com/mx/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)

Answer (score 3):

This definitely sounds like hardware issue, based on the fact that the HDD worked on a similar Macbook Pro.

Before we rule it as hardware, lets perform an Apple Hardware Test .

> Apple Hardware Test (AHT) contains a suite of diagnostics that will test the hardware of your computer. It's a great way to rule out a hardware issue when troubleshooting your computer.

[If your Mac was released after June 2013, use Apple Hardware Test.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)

[Otherwise, if your Mac was released prior to June 2013, use the Apple Diagnostics Test.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)

Fortunately Apple does a great job with documentation, so I'll avoid repeating the instructions mentioned in the provided links.

Once the test is complete, please reply with any error codes presented.

Comment: Thanks @Trent, I did the AHT. I ran the EXTENDED test. Nothing's wrong. Could it be that my MacBook has a Firmware Password? I tried removing the Firmware password by doing the CMD + R for Disk Utility but the Apple logo shows, the loading bar keeps loading and gets stuck at 50%

Comment: Strange. Lets try some obvious tests: [Reset PRAM by pressing keys during boot: Option-Command-P-R key](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph18761?locale=en_US) Also try booting without **anything** plugged in. No USBs, SDCards, Ethernet cord, etcetera.. Lastly, try booting into Safe Mode, then restart the computer using on-screen _Restart..._ option.

Comment: first of all thanks for the tips. I did the PRAM, when I do it it shows the Firmware password screen and then the Apple logo and the never ending Loading bar. Nothing is plugged in. Lastly, I tried Safe Mode (press left shift ) with no success. I really think it has something to do with something I read about GPU problems with EARLY 2011 Macs but not sure because according to Apple my MacBook don't apply.

Comment: Bummer. Don't worry, this will get resolved sooner or later. Is your computer under warranty still? Your HDD is bootable, no hardware failures are detected, yet your computer won't boot. Maybe its time for a trip to the Genius bar? Lets try booting into Verbose Mode by pressing (Command + V). Let me know what it says. Do any unusual beeps/flashes occur? These may indicate error codes.

Comment: Lastly, if you have an external hard drive enclosure, put your hard drive in it and boot your MacBook up holding the alt/option key and boot up using the external drive. Let me know if it boots.

Comment: It is not under warranty. I did swap my HDD to another MacBook Pro and booted perfectly. And my MacBook with the other HDD didn't boot. Verbose mode wont work... I call Apple Support and they suggested that it could be related to this https://www.apple.com/mx/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: If it is related to this issue, I'd say today is your lucky day. 'Apple or an Apple Authorized Service Provider will repair affected MacBook Pro systems, free of charge.' Give them a call and schedule a Genius Bar appointment. Let them know what the issue is, and please back up your data beforehand if possible.

Comment: Hope they can in fact help me for free. :( I had to change my keyboard long time ago because a Coffee spill and I suppose they wont apply the warranty :(

Comment: Best of luck! Keep us updated.

Comment: So, yes. They fixed my MacBook Pro and Yes, it was a faulty Video Card. :) Thanks a lot @Trent!

Comment: Great! Maybe answer your own question in case someone else has this same issue.